# Finding the number of paths of given length in a undirected unweighted graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, routes, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

'Length' of a path is the number of edges in the path.

Given a source and a destination vertex, I want to find the **number of paths** form the source vertex to the destination vertex of **given length** k.

- We can visit each vertex as many times as we want, so if a path from `a` to `b` goes like this: `a -> c -> b -> c -> b` it is considered valid. This means there can be cycles and we can go through the destination more than once.
- Two vertices can be connected by more than one edge. So if vertex `a` an vertex `b` are connected by two edges, then the paths , `a -> b` via edge 1 and `a -> b` via edge 2 are considered different.
- Number of vertices N is <= 70, and K, the length of the path, is <= 10^9.
- As the answer can be very large, it is to be reported modulo some number.

Here is what I have thought so far:

We can use [breadth-first-search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadt-first_search) without marking any vertices as visited, at each iteration, we keep track of the number of edges 'n_e' we required for that path and **product** 'p' of the number of duplicate edges each edge in our path has.

The search search should terminate if the `n_e` is greater than k, if we ever reach the destination with `n_e`equal to k, we terminate the search and  add `p` to out count of number of paths.

I think it we could use a depth-first-search instead of breadth first search, as we do not need the shortest path and the size of Q used in breadth first search might not be enough.

The second algorithm i have am thinking about, is something similar to [Floyd Warshall's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) using [this](http://www.iarcs.org.in/inoi/online-study-material/topics/floyd-warshall.php) approach . Only we dont need a shortest path, so i am not sure this is correct.

The problem I have with my first algorithm is that 'K' can be upto 1000000000 and that means my search will run until it has 10^9 edges and n_e the edge count will be incremented by just 1 at each level, which will be very slow, and I am not sure it will ever terminate for large inputs.

So I need a different approach to solve this problem; any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do all of the edges have weight 1?

Comment: @DennisMeng Yes, its an unweighted graph, i'll add it in the question

Answer (score 42, accepted):

So, here's a nifty graph theory trick that I remember for this one.

Make an adjacency matrix `A`. where `A[i][j]` is 1 if there is an edge between `i` and `j`, and 0 otherwise.

Then, the number of paths of length `k` between `i` and `j` is just the `[i][j]` entry of A^k.

So, to solve the problem, build `A` and construct A^k using matrix multiplication (the usual trick for doing exponentiation applies here). Then just look up the necessary entry.

EDIT: Well, you need to do the modular arithmetic inside the matrix multiplication to avoid overflow issues, but that's a much smaller detail.

Comment: "Then, the number of paths of length k between i and j is just the [i][j] entry of A^k." As every entry will be either 1 or 0, the number of paths will be either 0 or k?

Comment: No. You can do a quick induction proof to show correctness if you'd like, but A^k will not have only 0s and ks.

Comment: "A[i][j] is 1 if there is an edge between i and j, and 0 otherwise." you said that yourself

Comment: Yes, but that does not imply that A^k has only 0s and ks. I'm doing exponentiation, not multiplication by a scalar.

Comment: By A^k do you mean the whole matrix raised to k?

Comment: Yes. So, as a small example, A^5 is A*A*A*A*A, where * is matrix multiplication.

Comment: What is the usual trick of matrix exponentiation? Matrix multiplication will take O(n^3) time and doing that k times will be O(n^3 * k) which will be too slow

Comment: well, allocate more matrices via self-multiplication, say A0=A, A1=A0*A0, A2=A1*A1, etc, you'll end up only needing to multiply at most 2*ceil(log2(K)) times.

Comment: If you allow multiple edges between nodes and you define the adjacency matrix as _a[i][j] = e_ if there is e edges between _i_ and _j_, then the same is true for _A^k_.

Answer (score 7):

Actually the [i][j] entry of A^k shows the total different "walk", not "path", in each simple graph. We can easily prove it by "mathematical induction".
However, the major question is to find total different "path" in a given graph.
We there are a quite bit of different algorithm to solve, but the upper bound is as follow:

`(n-2)*(n-3)*...(n-k)` which "k" is the given parameter stating length of path.

Comment: This is indeed the correct word in graph theory, it should be noted. Finding paths is harder.

Answer (score 2):

Let me add some more content to above answers (as this is the extended problem I faced). The extended problem is

> Find the number of paths of length `k` in a given undirected tree.

The solution is simple for the given adjacency matrix `A` of the graph `G` find out A<sup>k-1</sup> and A<sup>k</sup> and then count number of the `1`s in the elements above the diagonal (or below).

Let me also add the python code.

```
import numpy as np

def count_paths(v, n, a):
    # v: number of vertices, n: expected path length
    paths = 0    
    b = np.array(a, copy=True)

    for i in range(n-2):
        b = np.dot(b, a)

    c = np.dot(b, a)
    x = c - b

    for i in range(v):
        for j in range(i+1, v):
            if x[i][j] == 1:
                paths = paths + 1

    return paths

print count_paths(5, 2, np.array([
                np.array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0]),
                np.array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1]),
                np.array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0]),
                np.array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0]),
                np.array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0])
            ])
```