# paths between two nodes in a directed graph with parallel edges

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph

Given a directed graph with parallel edges, I need to find the number of paths between the first and the last node in the input. Traversal of the same edge multiple times is allowed and parallel edges count as distinct paths.

The way I approached the problem is considering the number of paths between node s and node t that are no longer than k. The longest simple path in a graph with N nodes has N-1 vertices, thus if there are no cycles, path_count(s,t,n-1) and path_count(s,t,3n-3) should be equal. 3n -3 is basically a traversal of the longest simple path, a second traversal to the origin and yet another one to the target, establishing a cycle by reaching the target twice.

I have written some code to implement this. I use a vector called lookup to store intermediate results to speed things up. Here's what I've come up with:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>


using namespace std;
vector<vector<int>> lookup;

 int paths_count(vector<vector<int>> & graph, int k, int start, int dest)
 {
    if (lookup[k][start] != -1)
      return lookup[k][start];
    int result =0;
    if (k==1 && graph[start][dest]) //last hop, ends on target vertex
    {
       lookup[k][start] = graph[start][dest];
       return graph[start][dest];       
    }
    if (k==1) { // last hop, didn't reach target vertex
      lookup[k][start]=0;
      return 0;
    }
    for (int i=1; i < graph.size(); i++) {
       if (graph[start][i]>0) {
        if (i==dest) // assume no outbound edges from destination vertex
            result+=graph[start][dest];
        else {  
        // paths from i to dest
       int pc =paths_count(graph, k-1, i, dest);  
       /*
        total number of paths from start to dest through i is the 
        number of paths from i to dest
        times the number of edges from start to i
        */
        result+=graph[start][i]*pc; 
        }

      }
   }
   lookup[k][start]=result;
   return result;
}

int main() {

    int n, m,x,y;
    vector<vector<int>> graph;
    cin >> n >>m;

    graph.resize(n+1);
    lookup.resize(3*n - 2);

    for (int i=0; i < 3*n-2;++i)
        for (int j=0; j < n+1;++j)
            lookup[i].push_back(-1);

    for (int i=0; i < n+1; ++i)
        graph[i].resize(n+1);

    for (int i=0; i <m;++i) {
        cin >> x >>y;    
        graph[x][y]+=1;

    }

      int count1 = paths_count(graph,n-1,1,n);
      int count2 = paths_count(graph,3*n-3,1,n);


      if (count1 != count2)
          cout << "INFINITE PATHS";
      else
         cout << count1;


      return 0;
 }
```

the issue is that I have some given test cases, and some test cases I've written myself. My solution succeeds on my test cases and on some small-ish test cases but fails on the larges ones which I cannot manually debug (100 nodes, thousands of vertices). I've also tried a different idea with DFS that failed on the same test cases, leading me to believe that I fundamentally don't understand something about this problem. Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: what do you do if there is a loop in the path?
and this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14272119/finding-the-number-of-paths-of-given-length-in-a-undirected-unweighted-graph

Comment: if there's a loop, there will be more paths from u to v of length 3n-3 than of length n-1. This is the criteria I'm looking for, and if found a message is printed accordingly.

Comment: Not sure if this is the test case you failed, but if parallel edges is allowed, the answer can be exponetial in n. Imagine a graph with n nodes, there are two edges connectiing node i and i + 1.
Then there are 2^(n-1) path from node 1 to node n. I don't think int or even long long can handle it.