# Graph.pm - how to get all paths with particular length?

Tags: perl, graph

I have following example graph with 9 edges:

[image: graph]

Assuming that graph is undirected and weight of each edge is 1.

We can describe it programmatically using [Graph.pm](https://metacpan.org/pod/Graph) as

```
use Graph::Undirected;
my $g = Graph::Undirected->new; # An undirected graph.
$g->add_edge(1, 3);
$g->add_edge(3, 4);
$g->add_edge(4, 2);
$g->add_edge(1, 2);
$g->add_edge(1, 5);
$g->add_edge(1, 2);
$g->add_edge(1, 6);
$g->add_edge(6, 2);
$g->add_edge(2, 7);
```

How to get all paths from vertex `1` to vertex `2` which have length = 2 ?

I haven't found any method for it in [Graph.pm](https://metacpan.org/pod/Graph) :(

In my example it must return 2 paths, `[ 1, 5, 2 ]` and `[ 1, 6, 2 ]`

Comment: See also [Finding the number of paths of given length in a undirected unweighted graph](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14272119/2173773)

Comment: @HåkonHægland, thanks for a link, but unfortunately it describes how to find NUMBER of paths, but I need to get LIST of paths :)

Answer (score 2):

You had a bug in your edge setup, compare with my correct definition.

```
use Graph::Undirected;
my $g = Graph::Undirected->new;
$g->add_edge(1, 2);
$g->add_edge(1, 3);
$g->add_edge(1, 5);
$g->add_edge(1, 6);
$g->add_edge(2, 7);
$g->add_edge(3, 4);
$g->add_edge(4, 2);
$g->add_edge(5, 2);
$g->add_edge(6, 2);

for my $neighbour_of_v1 ($g->neighbours(1)) {
    next if 2 == $neighbour_of_v1; # direct neighbour, path is too short
    for my $neighbour_of_neighbour_of_v1 ($g->neighbours($neighbour_of_v1)) {
        next if 1 == $neighbour_of_neighbour_of_v1; # ignore backlink to start
        say "1-$neighbour_of_v1-$neighbour_of_neighbour_of_v1"
            if 2 == $neighbour_of_neighbour_of_v1;
    }
}
__END__
1-5-2
1-6-2
```